# error on download apk from own server with movile data

Tags: android

I was implement download apk from my own server, and install that, when i download with wifi its working fine, but when the movile is conected to internet with movile data the transfer is very low, and the apk not donwload, dont give me an error.
The code that i implemented is:

//Download the actual apk

```
                            InputStream inputStream = consumirWebService.ventaMovilUpdate("1", direccionUrlBase);
                            String pathApk = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+Dictionary.APK_NAME;
                            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pathApk);
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int bytesRead;
                            while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) !=-1){
                                os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                            inputStream.close();
                            os.flush();
                            os.close();
                            //Install the new apk
                            PackageInfo info = IMAdministrador.this.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(pathApk, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                            File file = new File(pathApk);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED, info.packageName);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            if(info.packageName != null){
                                IMAdministrador.INSTALL_APK_INFO.put(info.packageName, file);
                            }
```

I am thinking on download the apk by parts compressed with rest webservices. The weight of apk is 5MB, download each of a parts some thing like 1Mb by part, and when i have the five parts, uncompress and install. But really i dont have idea how can I do that.
Or if you have any best idea, I am very appreciate for your help.
Thanks in advance.